# Show all iterations of k-means algorithm converging in R?

Tags: r, k-means

I was just wondering if there was a simple way of showing all iterations of the k-means algorithm converging? Or would I have to manually calculate the distance measures for each point at every iteration?

For example, instead of just putting numbers into the k-means function and getting an output. Is it possible to show every iteration to getting to that output? Would be even better if this could easily be done visually using plots.

Comment: The `animation` package has a function `kmeans.ani` that can show an animation of k-means converging for a simple dataset.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look of the code of `kmeans` suggests that the bulk of the work is being done with a call to the Fortran function `c_kmns`, which means that you will need to manually write your own kmeans function in order to see each step of the optimization.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571236/my-own-k-means-algorithm-in-r) might be of use to you for writing your own function.